# Multiple spring boot web app on tomcat not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a tomcat 8.5.x with some applications already deployed. One of them uses spring-boot. Now I would like to deploy my own spring boot web app to the same tomcat, but seems not to work. I get this error message:

```
org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException-->org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$301352eb.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)
    ...
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$301352eb.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)
```

This is my `pom.xml`. As you can see I am using the newest version. I already tried it with many different versions like `1.5.0` or `2.0.2`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <groupId>com.example.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>tree</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: if you deploy on a Tomcat than `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` should have the scope `provided`

Comment: @DirkDeyne Tried it with and without provided. Same error.

Comment: do you have a `SpringBootServletInitializer` in your war?

Comment: @DirkDeyne Yes. I tried my application in a different tomcat 8.5.x (i buildet it from docker). No issues there. But the tomcat i need to deploy to is an existing one with different applications already deployed. Is it maybe a classpath problem?

Comment: I would guess that it is indeed a classpath problem

Comment: @RobohRob Do you have an idea how to fix it or debug it?

Comment: Exclude the duplicated class.. either explicitly in the maven pom.xml or have it removed from Tomcat

Comment: Somebody most likely added that class to tomcat for whatever reason

Comment: I did not find any jar shared by tomcat. As I understood tomcat creates for every web app a separate classpath and has a shared and common folder with all jars shared through all web apps.

Comment: I don't think you should use the spring-boot-maven-plugin. I am afraid when you use this plugin, it packages a fat-war (with tomcat-embedded in it).

Comment: These errors generally come from the fact that there is a shared jar somewhere, leading to class loader issues. (Class identity is based on the FQN of the class AND the class loader. So `org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback` loaded in 2 different class loaders are 2 different classes for Java. Really check your libraries etc. in tomcat to see what classes are in there. Remove those jars.